# How to have a script automatically detect when to stop and continue based on time of day

Tags: python, timedelay

I have a script that I am running through pycharm. Unfortunately, there are some parts of the script that have to be ran at certain times, and (again unfortunately) the time it takes for these parts to complete is longer than the time window allocated per day.

Therefore, what I would like is a way to pause execution and resume it the next day.

Something like this:

```
def foo(args):
   if time out of [1pm 3pm]:
       pause
   else:
       ...do stuff...
```

So let's say I run foo at 12pm, then the program would wait until 1 pm to continue running, and if  the time exceeds 3pm then it will pause again and continue next day at 1pm.

Is something like that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: What does PyCharm have to do with this? It's an IDE.

Comment: I don't know how to do this in Python -- indeed, I'm not sure that's possible. If you are running on linux, you can easily script to suspend execution by sending `SIGSTOP`, e.g. `pkill -SIGSTOP myscript` (to resume: `pkill -SIGCONT myscript`). On Windows you can also suspend execution, but it is not as easily scriptable.

Comment: @jarrmod You're right, I meant I am not running the script through a shell in order to do what Codebling was suggesting

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this through your OS; see Python's `os` package for internal controls.  Note that you need to pause the script, but *first* submit a `cron` job to resume it.  The details depend on your OS.

Comment: My OS is Windows 10. What do you mean "restart"? To be clear I don't want the script to start from scratch, just continue from where things paused.

Comment: My mistake; "resume" is the correct word.